# State not persisting - AngularJS Ionic Service fetching data from JSON file and then forgetting it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've been working on a pretty simple app just to try and familiarise myself with Angular and Ionic a bit, as well as having something to occupy by down-time at work, and I've run into an issue that's perplexing me a bit.  It's probably a very simple fix but I'm getting rather frustrated with trying to figure out what's going on with it.

***The context*** 
I have a simple three page (atm) app, consisting of a login screen, a registration screen and a landing screen with a couple of calls to action on it.  The idea is that the user data (name, id, etc.) will be persisted using a service (*user_svc* in this case) and can be used to display user-specific stuff which will be fetched later from some JSON from firebase or backand.

***The problem*** 
The issue I'm having is that the data doesn't seem to be available to all the functions in the service for whatever reason.  I have it logging the user object both where I am populating the object and where I am trying to access it and am getting the below output:

```
### IN THE POPULATOR ###
---   SETTER   ---
FETCHED USER:
ID:       ojohn1
FORENAME: Olly
SURNAME:  John


### IN THE ACCESSOR ###
---   GETTER   ---
FETCHED USER:
ID:       undefined
FORENAME: undefined
SURNAME:  undefined
```

The code for the service *user_svc* is below

```js
angular.module('app')
.service('user_svc', function($http) {
    return {
        user: {},
        setUser: function(userID) {
            $http.get('data/users.json').then(
                function(response) {
                    this.user = response.data.users[userID];
                    console.log(
                        '---   SETTER   ---' +
                        '\nFETCHED USER:' +
                        '\nID:       ' + this.user.id       +
                        '\nFORENAME: ' + this.user.forename +
                        '\nSURNAME:  ' + this.user.surname
                    );
                },
                function(response) {
                    console.log('File read failed');
                }
            )
        },
        getUser: function() {
            console.log(
                '---   GETTER   ---' +
                '\nFETCHED USER:' +
                '\nID:       ' + this.user.id       +
                '\nFORENAME: ' + this.user.forename +
                '\nSURNAME:  ' + this.user.surname
            );
            return this.user;
        }
    }
})
```

The *setUser* function is called once the user's login has been validated, and fetches the information from a JSON file I'm holding locally for the time being.  It populates the *user* object, which I would have thought made that object then accessible to the rest of the functions in the service - that's kind of the point of a service, right?  Sadly, this doesn't seem to be the case and I'm not entirely sure why, so if anyone could advise on why this is happening, that'd be much appreciated..

Comment: check your function scope, `this` isn't refering to the `this` you target.

Comment: Probably me being stupid but could you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('app')
.service('user_svc', function($http) {
    return {
        user: {},
        setUser: function(userID) {
            var that = this;// assign this to that
            $http.get('data/users.json').then(
                function(response) {
                    // here, this refers to window
                    // that refers to the this of setUser
                    that.user = response.data.users[userID];
                    console.log(
                        '---   SETTER   ---' +
                        '\nFETCHED USER:' +
                        '\nID:       ' + that.user.id       +
                        '\nFORENAME: ' + that.user.forename +
                        '\nSURNAME:  ' + that.user.surname
                    );
                },
                function(response) {
                    console.log('File read failed');
                }
            )
        },
        getUser: function() {
            console.log(
                '---   GETTER   ---' +
                '\nFETCHED USER:' +
                '\nID:       ' + this.user.id       +
                '\nFORENAME: ' + this.user.forename +
                '\nSURNAME:  ' + this.user.surname
            );
            return this.user;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm still getting the `undefined` values in the logs.  Doesn't seem to have worked, sadly..